# Demonstration for the following probability theory problem

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ a random variable such that $P(0\leq X\leq c)=1$ with $c>0$.

is it true that $\textrm{Var}(X)\leq {c^2\over 2}$?

I've tried to prove with the chebyshev theorem and I couldn't do it, and I've tried to find a counterexample and I couldn't do it too. help!

Comment: Can you please include those attempts you've mentioned?

Comment: Show us a little bit of your own effort please

Comment: I know that $E(X) \leq c$ because $E(X)=\int_0^c xf(x)dx \leq \int_0^c cf(x)dx=c$, and I tried to use the Markov Theorem and the Chevyshev Theorem but there's no way to continue. And for the counterexamples I tried with discrete uniform functions, exponential but the propposition is always true.

Answer (score 4):

Variance of a random variable does not change if you add a constant to it; so if $Y=X-c/2$, then $\operatorname{var}(X)=\operatorname{var}(Y)$. Now

$$\operatorname{var}(Y)=\operatorname{E}[Y^2]-(\operatorname{E}[Y])^2 \leqslant \operatorname{E}[Y^2]\leqslant \operatorname{E}[(c/2)^2]= \frac{c^2}{4} < \frac{c^2}{2} $$

Comment: this fact is clear, but why can I use it for the solution of the problem?

Comment: @JuanPabloPadillaVargas You can prove the first statement if you must: $\operatorname{var}(X) =E[(X-E[X])^2] =E[(X-\frac{c}{2}-E[X-\frac{c}{2}])^2] =  E[(Y-E[Y])^2] = \operatorname{var}(Y)$